# Windows 7 x64: Moving an install from a 2TB HDD to a 64GB SSD seamlessly. Possible? Worth it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, 64-bit, ssd, migration

Let's call the 2TB HDD old install and the 64GB SSD new install... both are running identical Win 7 x64 builds. Here's what I'm thinking:

- Windows Easy Transfer for profile migration
- Map "special folder locations" (desktop, prog files, docs, etc) in the new install to the 2TB drive
- Dump the registry from the old install into backup.reg
- Replace all occurrences of special folders with new locations in backup.reg
- Import backup.reg into the new install.

Has anyone attempted something like this? I've searched to no avail.

Aside: I've pulled something like this off on XP with a bit of troubleshooting. I've thoroughly explored the innards of 95/98/2000/xp and a fair bit of 7x64 so far... tempted to take the leap.

Comment: You might consider using a program like Acronis to image the C drive, then restore that image to the SSD...http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/

Comment: What Moab said - just image it over.  I use Casper, personally. http://www.fssdev.com/products/casper/

Comment: Thought of imaging it, but the install on C:\ is too bloated (as I mentioned, the C drive is 2TB and the SSD is 64GB). The C:\Windows directory alone is 18GB vs 10GB on the fresh SSD install.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do a fresh installation, and then work in migrating your settings over from the older drive you have.

Go through, install whatever program you had on and then copy over the appdata to keep your settings.

Comment: Ended up going this route, mapping my data folders to the 2TB HDD, and doing some custom editing with BEncode. Not exactly seamless, but tried and true.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no issues with the old install (2TB) and you just want to move the install to the new disk (ssd) I'd use a disk cloning utility to move the whole package to the new disk.

You'd need to of course re-partition the old disk to have OS partition that fits to the ssd. And best have all folder links disabled or moved to point only to OS partition before cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you move all data to another disk so as Windows, programs and user files are less then 64GB. Then clode the old hard disk to SSD with Acronis as suggested. It could boot as is, else use Windows 7 DVD-ROM to "repair" starup problems and it will work. To be 100% sure, use manual cloning and select to leave the partitions as they are (no resizing). I have done that many times (cloning small disk to new larger). If you do it properly, so save yourself many hours of reinstalling everything from start, let alone the hours of backing up tons of data!